# Why my second ng-model does not return value as inserted?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code with textarea1 and textarea2. My problem I was unable to manipulate the `ng-model` on textarea2.

**If I change anything in textarea2...nothing was happened**

Anyone can help me figure out this problem? Thanks.

You may see the codes I've done so far.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.model1 = "Test1";
  $scope.catch = function(model1)
  {
     $scope.model2 = model1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Textarea 1
  <textarea onkeypress="{{catch(model1)}}" ng-model="model1"></textarea>
  
  <br/>
  Text area 2
  <textarea ng-model="model2"></textarea>
  
  <hr/>
  Textarea1: {{model1}} <br/>
  Textarea2: {{model2}}
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: First of all, i wouldn't use the word `catch` since it's a reserved JS function. Secondly, use `ng-keypress="someFunction( model1 )"`

Comment: onkeypress is called anytime there is a keypress.  not just when you are in that textbox and press a key

Comment: @big_water is right. Keypress is being fired everywhere and model2 is constantly being updated to model1. Any reason why you are using such an old version of AngularJS? Ironically, if you update to at least 1.5, Angular will tell you not to use the keypress and it will kill it; thus allowing your page to work as expected (model2 getting updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change `onkeypress` for `ng-change`?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.model1 = "Test1";

  $scope.catch = function(model1)
  {
     $scope.model2 = model1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Textarea 1
  <textarea ng-change="catch(model1)" ng-model="model1"></textarea>
  
  <br/>
  Text area 2
  <textarea ng-model="model2"></textarea>
  
  <hr/>
  Textarea1: {{model1}} <br/>
  Textarea2: {{model2}}
</div>

</div>
```